# No decimal pattern found for numbering system:prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: fatal-error, prestashop-1.7

when i am trying to migrate from local version of prestashop 1.7.6 to a distant server (on ovh) i have this error can you help me please
Fatal error: Uncaught PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Exception\LocalizationException: No decimal pattern found for numbering system: in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Locale.php:219 Stack trace: #0 /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/Specification/Factory.php(60): PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\CLDR\Locale->getDecimalPattern() #1 /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/Locale/Repository.php(182): PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Specification\Factory->buildNumberSpecification(Object(PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\CLDR\Locale), 3, true) #2 /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/Locale/Repository.php(149): PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Locale\Repository->getNumberSpecification('fr-FR') #3 /home/vrqlcrq/www/classes/controller/Controller.php(189): PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Locale\Repository->getLocale('fr-FR') #4 /home/vrqlcrq/www/classes/controller/FrontController.php(271): ControllerCore->init() #5 /home/vrqlcrq/www/classes/controller/Controller.p in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Locale.php on line 219

back office
[image]
thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an incompatible cache issue to me.

Try deleting everything inside **/var/cache** before restoring the backup.

Comment: the same problem remains i also verified the ps_currency_lang ..
any suggestion please